# New Transport Rule in Exchange Server

Tags: c#, web-services, powershell, exchange-server

I have a website working with exchange web services. I want to implement a new feature in that. For that i need to create a transport rule by using exchange webservices.

I googled and searched everything but not getting any transport rule example with exchange webservices.

Can anybody have example for this?

I saw examples with powershell but from my ASP.NET application i want to create new transport rule with exchange service it self.

Comment: Did my answer cover off everything you where after? did you want more info on calling PowerShell from C#

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just cannot do it using the EWS API:

> No you can't set Transport rules from EWS, EWS is a mailbox access API and setting Transport Rule would be considered an Administrative Task so you need to use and Admin API which for Exchange is still the Exchange Management Shell.

[SOURCE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d6aab0a8-2ee5-405a-ab5d-d34b2758bfc7/using-mail-transport-rules-and-the-exchange-aws-api?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment)

Comment: No worries, Look in to the system.managment.automation dll for C# it allows you to have powershell commands in your C# code.